# Removing Page Numbers from Footer but KEEP the footer?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I've had trouble finding a good solution to this problem. I have a custom footer that needs to be on every page of this document. Page numbering needs to start with the first page, but not be visible until the third page in lowercase roman numerals. It then switches to arabic numbering by about the seventh page. I've got the switch from roman to arabic fine and all the page numbers are showing up, but how do I remove *just* the page number from the first two pages and keep the rest of my footer in tact? Everything I've seen so far ends up removing the whole footer from these two pages, but it's a legal issue if they aren't there.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]
{\footnotesize words\\
words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words}
\fancyfoot[C]
{\begin{flushright}
\noindent\mbox{}\hfill \thepage \hfill\mbox{}\makebox[0pt][r]{{\footnotesize Internal Number}}\\
\end{flushright}
\footnotesize words\\
words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead[C]{words\\
words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words}
\fancyfoot[C]
{\begin{flushright}
{Internal Number}\\
\end{flushright}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

I'm not sure what other context you'll need to help with this, so please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code will create a 9 page document. The first two pages will be numbered but will not display the page number. Pages 3 to 6 will have the page number in Roman lowercase and finally from page 7 the page number will be shown in Arabic characters.

The other parts of the footer will not be modified.

Pages #1 and #2
[image: a]

Pages #3 and #4
[image: b]

Pages #6 and #7
[image: c]

Pages #8 and #9
[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]
{\footnotesize words\\
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words}
\fancyfoot[C]
{\begin{flushright} \noindent\mbox{}\hfill \ifnum\thepage<3\relax\else\ifnum\thepage<7\roman{page}\else\arabic{page}\fi\fi\hfill\mbox{}\makebox[0pt][r]{{\footnotesize Internal Number}}\\
    \end{flushright}
    \footnotesize words\\
    words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words}
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text ONLY for testing

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-24]
\end{document}
```